# Ios connect bluetooth devices

Tags: swift, ios-bluetooth

Im using BeeTee library for searing nearby bluetooth devices. It's work fine but i don't understand how to connect devices using BeeTee library.
Anyone help me for this.

Comment: check this it may help you https://github.com/michaeldorner/BeeTee/issues/2

Comment: i already check this link but there is no solution for connect bluetooth.

Answer (score 0):

BeeTee Library not supported for device connectivity.

Read limitation in 
[https://github.com/michaeldorner/BeeTee][1]